# Hook for a JS library in a custom module not working drupal 8

Tags: 8, javascript, hooks

Well I have created a JS to validate a form, and when I try to attach the hook in my custom module the JS its not showing. My custom module it's call "ajax_form"

My ajax_form.libraries.yml

```
ajax_form:
  version: 1
  js:
    js/ajax_form.js: {}
  dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

My ajax_form.module

```
<?php
function ajax_form_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'ajax_form/ajax_form';
}
```

I have a `console.log('test');` in the first line of my JS but this is not displaying.

I have run out of ideas of what it be. Also I'm new to Drupal maybe is that.

Comment: verify ajax_form is your module name it should be in `YOUR_MODULE_NAME/YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME` eg: `$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME/ajax_form';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrong indentation. Dependencies need two spaces indentation:

```
ajax_form:
  version: 1
  js:
    js/ajax_form.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```