# What's the minimum viable example to attach JavaScript using a page hook?

Tags: javascript

Here my module file following [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) precisely for declaring js files of a module and attaching the created library. But can't see my module js file within the page code source.
Here is my files content:
my_module.librarises.yml :

```
my_module.lib:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/my-module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/drupal
```

my_module.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
 function my_module_page_attachments(array &$page) {
      $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.lib';
 }
```

my-module.js (in my_module/js directory):

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('Loaded...');
    });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

In code source I can see "my_module/my_module.lib":

{"path": ..., {"libraries":.., "my_module/my_module.lib",..

But can't get the file js.

**SOLVED:**
it was a typing error while naming libraries.yml:
my_module.libraries.yml instead of my_module.librarises.yml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hook for a JS library in a custom module not working drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261578/hook-for-a-js-library-in-a-custom-module-not-working-drupal-8)

Comment: Looks like wrong indentation to me in `my_module.libraries.yml` which in your question also is named falsely as ~~my_module.librarises.yml~~.

Comment: An obvious thing but did you flush the sites caches after you created/edited your .libraries.yml file?

Comment: @leymannx the indentation is respected as it should in my local I've just checked it twice..

Comment: Then please update your question to reflect the indentation accordingly. And please remove the typos as well. (librarises.yml)

Comment: @LeighMason I flushed the cash using Drush cr command also I uninstalled my module and enabled it again after each .libraries.yml modification

Comment: @leymannx "And please remove the typos as well. (librarises.yml)" sorry didn't get it! what should I remove exactly?

Comment: Typos = typing errors. This file is supposed to be named `my_module.libraries.yml`. **libraries** not librarises :)

Comment: @leymannx oh thanks a lot dude you save my day! it works now :) thank you very much!

Comment: @leymannx should I delete the question?

Comment: Ha cool! You can delete it. It will get deleted anyways, I think, now that it's closed as off-topic.